# How to reload a php page automatically from server and not from browser

Tags: php

Is that possible?I know how to refresh a page with header commands or javascript but this demands that the user will constantly have a browser opened.I want to build an automated bot that will not need my computer opened all the time.

Comment: U want to take a look into [cron](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/), not every webhost has cron support tho

Comment: thanks but this is the only way??

Answer (score 3):

Run the PHP script from a command line with your CRON or Windows Task Scheduler.  Create a new Task, and execute that task as often as you like without a user or a browser.

```
C:\php\php.exe -f C:\My_Folder\My_Script.php
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron - "The software utility cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems."

Answer (score 0):

So you want to execute your script independently of web-calls, the usual approach would be to launch your PHP-Script using cron.
You can also use 3d party service such as https://www.setcronjob.com/ as "external" cron - if the intervals are not too narrow...

Comment: you are perfect.that service seems awesome!